# why does my glassfish server stop?

Tags: glassfish

I have a GF3 server in production. Sometimes, it just stops responding. At least, all web applications do. CPU / memory usage is low, but I can't get any web app on port 8080 to work. Nothing in the logs (5 minutes gap in server.log until I restarted manually). Everything fine after restart... for a while.

Took a jstack output before restarting. Didn't find anything interesting (no code from my apps running, no locks...).

Version = GlassFish v3 (build 74.2), JRE version 1.6.0_19

UPDATE: it comes back by itself after some time (still not acceptable for my clients :-( )

UPDATE: I switched to a new installation of GF3.1 (was 3.0.1). At the moment (after a couple of hours), one of the applications that is deployed there has 177 sessions. Problem is: I only have about 12 users (where did all those sessions come from?). Same applications deployed with other name has 6 sessions. Could I just run out of thread pools or something like that?

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question, unfortunately.

Comment: Would be great if you can provide some information before the halt from the log, it can be found here: /opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/my-domain/config$ less logging.properties 
com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler.file=/var/log/domains/my-domain/server.log

Comment: There isn't any information in the logs. Nothing gets log from the moment the apps become unresponsive. I mean, it was working at 15.50 but not at 15.51 and there isn't anything in the logs between this. Any other information I could provide that would be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest hooking up Visual VM with the GF plugin.

http://visualvm.java.net/index.html

Then when your server "stops", take a look and see what's going on.

Comment: Didn't had the chance to see the problem live until now. It did happen once again, but it came back by itself, I was too late.

Comment: You can leave Visual VM up and running, but it seems to quit graphing properly after a few hours. So if you think you're going to see the issue, fire it up and let it sit.

Comment: Lot of GC time used, heap is at max. I think I just need to pay for a new server...

Comment: Maybe you have a leak? Is your class count increasing? Also you might try adding -XX:+DisableExplicitGC to your jvm options.

Comment: Upgraded the server 1 year ago, everything is fine since then.

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing interesting in the stack trace, then the problem is likely to be between the client and GlassFish.
In any case I would also suggest upgrading to the latest JDK (_24) and GlassFish (3.1).

Comment: I can confirm the problem when it is blocked. It seems the requests are still being logged in access log, but don't reach the jsf servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I was using connection pooling with MySQL, and in some places I forgot to close the database connection. After fixing those mistakes everything was fine.